# CSS won't change font colors for links within DIV

Tags: html, css

Not sure what I am missing, but my HTML is ignoring my CSS style sheet specs for links.
All my other CSS definitions work fine throughout the page.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

My CSS page includes:

```
.footer {
    background:url( );
    margin:0;
    height:70px;
    clear:both;
}

.footer {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 175%;
    font:normal 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#999;
}

a.footer {
    font:normal 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#999;
    line-height: 175%;
}

a.footer:link {
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.footer:visited {
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.footer:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

My webpage includes:

```
<div class="footer">
<a href="http://www.someurl.org"> Page Title 1</a><br />
<a href="http://www.someurl.org/credits_policies.html">Page Title 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Change all `a.footer` to `.footer a`

- `a.footer` means all `<a>` with class `footer`
- `.footer a` means `<a>` within an element with class `footer` which is your `<div>`.

Your CSS should be like this:

```
.footer a { font:normal 11px helvetica,arial,sans-serif; color:#999; line-height: 175%; } 

.footer a:link { outline:none; text-decoration:none; }

.footer a:visited { outline:none; text-decoration:none; }

.footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
```

Here are some tutorials for class selector and descendant selector:

[Class Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

[Descendant Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

Comment: Wow - that was too easy! Thanks for the quick response and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change `a.footer` into `.footer a`. Your current css tries to set the style of links which have the class "footer", themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
.footer a
{
//your syles
}
```

Currently the `CSS` is being applied to all the links with class `footer` which is not the case.Your `div` has that class

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BGJ7b/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change all `a.footer` to `.footer a` as `a.footer` is nothing here which mean applying style to `a`with `class footer`

Answer (score 0):

hi now used to this

```
.footer a{
// your css here 
}
```

**and used title this formated**

```
<a href="#" title="Your title here ">helo</a>
```